# Как обработать начальный роут (корневой) в backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, javascript

Сабж. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
var HellospaceRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "/":         "root", 
        "signup":   "signup",  
        "login":    "login"
    }
});
```

Но корневой роутер не обрабатывается. В доках на этот счёт ничего не сказано, увы.

Comment: роут на `#/ ` ? для корня он может '' должен быть ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TaCVE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

дефолтный роутер имеет индекс '' (пустая строка):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TaCVE/

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'items/:id': 'itemDetails',
        '':  'root',
    },

    itemDetails: function (id) {
        console.log('id: %o', id);
    },
    root: function() {
    console.log('root');
    }
});

var router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Странно. Работает. Я тоже сперва так сделал. И не заработало. Буду думать почему.

Comment: кстати, посмотрите в обновленный fiddle, там демонстрация куда указывает '/'

Comment: Меня интересует вот что. Если я захожу на /, контент не вырисовывается и если менять хеш - тоже, но если я захожу, например, на /#/login контент отрисовывается. И даже /#/ соответствует главной. Но на / не реагирует также.

Comment: а console.log() срабатывает ? может надо еще и DomReady подождать ?

Comment: Ваш пример срабатывает, что странно. Я так в нём вызываю.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TaCVE/ вот так не работает ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TaCVE/5/ а вот так работает

Comment: Я всё понял. Моя модель создаётся до создания вьюхи, и поэтому первое событие change не обрабатывается. Добавил trigger('change') у модели после создания вьюхи и всё заработало.